# Not sure what this code is doing

Tags: c++

What is the difference between the two results here?  I have seen things like this but don't understand at all.  Imagine the following program:

```
int main() {

vector<int> v(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) v[i] = i; 

cout << v[3] << endl;
cout << v[3] - '0';

return 0;
}
```

v[3] will return 3
and v[3]-'0' will return -45

I am just curious about this.

Comment: you have to wonder about what means `'0'`. Tell me what does it mean for you ?

Comment: Your v[i]=i; should be under your for, and imo its always a good idea to have it inside brackets as well

Comment: @Matt : brackets really shouldn't be necessary for something so trivial, but I agree it's good practice to always use them - you never know when you'll want to put other statements in your `for` loop, so you'll have to add them then anyway. In any case, yes, `for` block/statement should always be under the `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers are correct, except nobody mentioned the reason, C++ integer promotions require that `char` type is promoted to `int` in `v[3] - '0'` expression, had the types be different (e.g. `vector<char> v(4)`), the answer would be quite different as well.

Answer (score 2):

`'0'` is the *character* zero, which has ASCII code 48. Hence, `v[3] - '0'` is actually `v[3] - 48`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at ASCII table '0' is equal to decimal 48. 3-48=-45